# Double-click action for menu bar icon in Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I'm writing a small Mac OSX app that displays a menu bar icon. When clicked, a menu pops up.

I'd like to have a "default" action for the menu bar icon. Basically, to execute an action when double-clicking it, without having to select the action from the menu.

I looked over the Apple docs and there's is such a thing in `NSStatusItem` called `doubleAction`, but it's soft deprecated and does not (seem to) work. More over, the docs it says to use the `button` property, but trying to do so results in the compiler error shown below:

[image]

Any code or guidance are much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think it means to set the action on the button. Not doubleAction.

Comment: Of course, but that's the single-click action - not the double-click. On single click it pops the menu and that's ok. I want to be able to add an action for double-click.

Answer (score 3):

The situation as it stands today (Xcode 7.3.1, OSX 10.11.4):

- the `doubleAction` of `NSStatusItem` is deprecated (and NOT actually working).
- Apple tells you to use the `button` property - but there's no header for `doubleAction` (I wonder if the implementation exists). Oh, it's also read-only.
- there are no other options regarding left/right/double click in any of the `NSStatusItem`'s properties.

The **workaround**: create a category for NSButton (the exact same that Apple was talking about) and implement a custom click handler that posts a notification when a double click was detected, like the following:

```
@implementation NSButton (CustomClick)

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    if (self.tag != kActivateCustomClick) {
        [super mouseDown:event];
        return;
    }

    switch (event.clickCount) {
        case 1: {
            [self performSelector:@selector(callMouseDownSuper:) withObject:event afterDelay:[NSEvent doubleClickInterval]];
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            [NSRunLoop cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"double_click_event" object:nil];
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)callMouseDownSuper:(NSEvent *)event {
    [super mouseDown:event];
}

@end
```

As you can see, this handler only handles `NSButton` instances that have a specific `tag` value.

When a click is detected, I defer the call to `super` for handling by the system's double-click interval. If within that time I receive another click, I cancel the call to `super` and treat it as a double-click.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSApp.currentEvent`

```
self.statusItem.button.target = self;
self.statusItem.button.action = @selector(clickOnStatusItem:);
```

...

```
- (void)clickOnStatusItem:(id)sender {
    if (NSApp.currentEvent.clickCount == 2) {
        // Double click on status item
    }
}
```

also, you can process a right mouse button on the status bar item