# How to add a doubleClick action to a datePicker

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsdatepicker

How can I set a doubleClick event in an `NSDatePicker` and make doubleClick change its selected date the same as click does?

```
let doubleClick = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleClickEvent))
doubleClick.numberOfClicksRequired = 2
uploadDatePicker.addGestureRecognizer(doubleClick)
```

I add this ClickGestureRecognizer for my DatePicker. When I double clicked in the DatePicker, it can correctly get into the function `doubleClickEvent` but the selected date didn't change.

How should I code to make the DatePicker change its selected date when user double click any date?

Comment: Show the obj doubleClickEvent function + the name of the class under which you are writing code.

Comment: Double click does change the date if you remove the click recognizer. See [Double-click action for menu bar icon in Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47031117/4244136)